# Some packets being stopped before reaching firewall

Tags: debian, iptables, linux-networking

I have an application listening on port 20514:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 192.168.100.213:20514   0.0.0.0:*                           3629/python3
```

I can see packets entering my computer with tcpdump

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp0s25 -n -N udp port 20514
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s25, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:54:56.832307 IP 172.18.248.3.514 > 192.168.100.213.20514: SYSLOG user.critical, length: 111
```

iptables is (at this point) allowing everything. Note that it doesn't report any packets that match the rule from 172.18.248.0/28, despite us seeing one above. In any cast, -P INPUT is ACCEPT

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 134 packets, 79373 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     192.168.100.0/24     anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
 4745  282K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     10.8.0.0/24          anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     172.18.248.0/28      anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 533 packets, 89933 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-USER (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain LOGACCEPT (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             LOG level info prefix "INPUT:ACCEPT:"
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

So it seems that packets are being stopped after entering the interface but before it reaches the firewall.

Where else can I look to see why packets entering my machine aren't reaching the application?

Comment: Check the `nat` table.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me there. I will update with solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that Docker was making interfaces with networks that overlapped the source address of the packets.

Even though I had cleared out all of the rules docker made in IPtables, I ended up having to change /etc/docker/daemon.json to start networks at a different IP range. I then removed all my containers and deleted all the networks that Docker had created. There may be a less destructive way to accomplish deleting the docker network interfaces, but I wasn't attached to anything.

After that packets were coming through. So it seemed to be the network interfaces themselves that were interfering.